# Active Record Associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, model-associations

I have a model `Persons::Names::Log` and another model `Persons::Address`. I want to create an association between `Log` and `Address`. Is it possible? What statements should I write in both the model files?

`Edit` :

I want to have an association like `Persons::Names::Log.last.address`

Answer (score 1):

From http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#controlling-association-scope :

> To associate a model with a model in a different namespace, you must
>   specify the complete class name in your association declaration.

The following is an example of the associations with the given class names:

```
module Persons
  module Names
    class Log
      has_one :address, class_name: "Persons::Address"
    end
  end

  class Address
    belongs_to :log, class_name: "Persons::Names::Log"
  end
end
```

Comment: Adjust the associations as per your requirements / class structures; the main thing is to specify the full class name.

Comment: In addition, you will have to make sure there is an appropriate database field for the relevant association by running a migration. The migration will be specific to the relationship between the two entities. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html  for details on the migrations corresponding to each relationship.

Comment: Will an association be possible if there is no common field in both the tables?

Answer (score 1):

Specify the class name with scopes :

```
    # app/persons/names/log.rb
    module Persons
      module Names
        class Log < ActiveRecord::Base
          has_one :address, class_name: "Persons::Address"
        end
      end
    end

   # app/persons/address.rb
    module Persons
      class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :log, class_name: "Persons::Names::Log"
      end
    end
```